# TabLayout and TextViewCompat.getMaxLines() throws No static method found

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-tablayout

I am using TabLayout in "com.android.support:design:23.1.0"

it throws exception:

```
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getMaxLines(Landroid/widget/TextView;)I in class Landroid/support/v4/widget/TextViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat' appears in /data/app/com.tabe3.news-1/base.apk:classes38.dex)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.update(TabLayout.java:1325)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1185)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:655)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:690)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:385)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:360)
```

I fount it using "TextViewCompat.getMaxLines()"

I tried this line of code only in my code, it also throws the same exception.

Please advise.